# Field error proc with field name in error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionview

I am trying to add field errors in rails with `field_error_proc`. But I could not find a way to add the error with the field name. Below is the code that I am using to generate a field with errors in rails.

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = proc do |html_tag, instance|
  if html_tag =~ /^<label/
    %(#{html_tag}).html_safe
  else
    %(#{html_tag}<div class="help-block"><ul role="alert"><li>#{instance.error_message.first}</li></ul></div>).html_safe
  end
end
```

below is the output of the above code. What I want is to have an error with field name like "Email is required" so as to have the common pattern for error(same as FE validation error)

[image: Error generated with field error proc for presence validation]

This is the output of the FE validation.

[image]

Comment: Can you add debug logs for instance and instance.error_message

Answer (score 2):

If you display the content of your `instance` block argument you should see something like this:

```rails
#<ActionView::Helpers::Tags::TextField:0x00007f54102118d8 @method_name="email", @object_name="user" # ...(more)
```

So in order to get the **method name** of the validated input you could use:

```ruby
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = proc do |html_tag, instance|
  method_name = instance.instance_variable_get("@method_name").humanize
  if html_tag =~ /^<label/
    %(#{html_tag}).html_safe
  else
    %(#{html_tag}<div class="help-block"><ul role="alert"><li>#{method_name} #{instance.error_message.first}</li></ul></div>).html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: See alternative solution. I couldn't my entire suggested edit in this comment.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid calling `html_safe` ?  Rubocop and Brakeman don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one adjustment here. Rather than call `humanize` I would use the object's class to call `human_attribute_name`. This has the added benefit of letting you set the attribute name in your locales so it's consistent with your labels.

Swap the first line for:

```
method_name = instance.instance_variable_get("@method_name")
human_method_name = instance.object.class.human_attribute_name(method_name)
```